# Hyperbolic identities proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove this hyperbolic identity:

$ \sinh ^{2}x= \frac{1}{2}(-1+ \cosh (2x)) $

$ \sinh ^{2}x= \frac{1}{2}(-1+ (\cosh ^{2}x-\sinh ^{2}x)) $

$ \sinh ^{2}x= \frac{1}{2}(-1+(1-\sinh ^{2}x- \sinh ^{2}x)) $

$ \sinh ^{2}x= \frac{1}{2}(-1+1-2 \sinh ^{2}x) $

$ \sinh ^{2}x= -\sinh ^{2}x $

In the last step,  what is my mistake?

Comment: Line $2$: $\cosh(2x)=\cosh^2(x)+\sinh^2(x)$, not $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)$. In fact, the latter expression is always equal to $1$, implying that $\cosh^2(x)=1+\sinh^2(x)$, not $1-\sinh^2(x)$ (you wrote this in line $3$).

Comment: I suggest you write down what identities you used and confirm them with the book/source from where you are studying.

Comment: I can't find my mistake ,  let me see what are the hyperbolic identities that I have to use @AlannRosas

Comment: Can you recommend me a book for this? @ultralegend5385

Comment: I got it, I was mixing the identity of the cosine of the double angle, thank you so much @AlannRosas

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

If you are not aware of the hyperbolic identities, I advise you to make use of the definitions involved:

\begin{align*}
\cosh(2x) - 1 & = \frac{e^{2x} + e^{-2x}}{2} - 1\\\\
& = \frac{e^{2x} - 2 + e^{-2x}}{2}\\\\
& = \frac{e^{2x} - 2e^{2x}e^{-2x} + e^{-2x}}{2}\\\\
& = \frac{(e^{2x} - e^{-2x})^{2}}{2}\\\\
& = 2\times\left[\frac{e^{2x} - e^{-2x}}{2}\right]^{2}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?